Flatpak Thunderbird will not open links
I have just updated to Kubuntu 24.04, and installed Flatpak Thunderbird (and later, Flatpak Firefox).
I copied my ~/.thunderbird -directory to ~/.var/app/org.mozilla.Thunderbird, which made the transition very seamless.
However, whenever I click on a link in an e-mail, nothing happens.
I have tried a lot of tricks found on the internet:

In System Settings -> Default Applications, I tried both Firefoxes (the .deb one and the Flatpak one)
sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser lists 1 firefox (the .deb one at /usr/bin/firefox) and /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable at auto mode and manual mode. I tried each of them, to no avial. How would I add the flatpak one here?
In Thunderbird Settings -> General - Files & Attachments, for http and https I tried


Use System Handler




.deb Firefox (/usr/bin/firefox)




Flatpak Firefox (/var/lib/flatpak/exports/bin/org.mozilla.Firefox)




Always Ask


In Thunderbird Settings -> Configuration Editor, I set network.protocol-handler.warn-external.http and network.protocol-handler.warn-external.https to "true"
I removed the ~/.var/app/org.mozilla.Thunderbird/.thunderbird/.default/mimeTypes.rdf

My handlers.json looks like
{"defaultHandlersVersion":{},"mimeTypes":
  {"application/vnd.ms-excel":{"action":4,"ask":true,"extensions":["xls","xlb","xlt"]},
  "application/x-font-pcf":{"action":0,"ask":true,"extensions":["pcf","pcf.z"]},
  "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document":{"action":4,"ask":true,"extensions":["docx"]},
  "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet":{"action":4,"ask":true,"extensions":["xlsx"]},
  "text/plain":{"action":4,"ask":true,"handlers":[{"name":"thunderbird","path":"/usr/bin/thunderbird"}],
  "extensions":["asc","txt","text","pot","brf","srt"]},
  "application/pdf":{"action":4,"extensions":["pdf"],"handlers":[{"name":"Okular","path":"/usr/bin/okular"},{"name":"Inkscape Vector Graphics Editor","path":"/usr/bin/inkscape"}]},
  "image/x-png":{"action":4,"ask":true},
  "application/ics":{"action":0,"ask":true,"extensions":["ics"]},
  "image/gif":{"action":2,"ask":true,"handlers":[{"name":"inkscape","path":"/usr/bin/inkscape"}],"extensions":["gif"]},
  "image/jpeg":{"action":4,"ask":true,"handlers":[{"name":"Geeqie","path":"/usr/bin/geeqie"}],"extensions":["jpeg","jpg","jpe","jfif","pjpeg","pjp"]},
  "image/jp2":{"action":2,"ask":true,"handlers":[{"name":"GIMP Image Editor","path":"/usr/bin/gimp-2.8"}],"extensions":["jp2","jpg2"]},
  "application/x-7z-compressed":{"action":4,"ask":true,"extensions":["7z"]},
  "text/html":{"action":2,"extensions":["htm","html","shtml","ehtml"],"handlers":[{"name":"org.mozilla.firefox","path":"/run/user/1000/doc/e2e4af3c/org.mozilla.firefox"}]},
  "image/png":{"action":4,"ask":true,"extensions":["png"]},
  "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation":{"action":4,"ask":true,"extensions":["pptx"]},
  "image/tiff":{"action":4,"ask":true,"extensions":["tiff","tif"]},
  "application/ms-tnef":{"action":2,"ask":true,"extensions":["dat"]},
  "application/x-iwork-pages-sffpages":{"action":4,"ask":true},
  "application/vnd.openstreetmap.data+xml":{"action":0,"ask":true,"extensions":["osm"]}
 },
  "schemes":{
    "http":{"action":2,"handlers":[{"name":"org.mozilla.firefox","path":"/run/user/1000/doc/e2e4af3c/org.mozilla.firefox"},{"name":"google-chrome","path":"/run/user/1000/doc/f2b075a5/google-chrome"},{"name":"org.mozilla.Thunderbird","path":"/run/user/1000/doc/cf642bac/org.mozilla.Thunderbird"}]},
    "https":{"action":2,"handlers":[{"name":"org.mozilla.firefox","path":"/run/user/1000/doc/e2e4af3c/org.mozilla.firefox"},{"name":"google-chrome","path":"/run/user/1000/doc/f2b075a5/google-chrome"}]}
   },"isSVGXMLAlreadyMigrated":true}

(whitespace added for clarity)
When in the TB settings -> General -> Files & Attachments, for https I click on Application Details, under org.mozilla.firefox I see "this application is located at /run/user/1000/doc/e2e4af3c/org.mozilla.firefox", even when I explicitly put in /var/lib/flatpak/exports/bin/org.mozilla.firefox. However, both are a shell script with as contents
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/bin/flatpak run --branch=stable --arch=x86_64 org.mozilla.firefox "$@"

I restarted my entire pc several times, and thunderbird as well. But to no avail.
I have no idea where to look next.
I'm using Kubuntu 24.04 (on X11), Firefox 133 (flatpak)/113 (.deb), Thunderbird 128.5.2esr
I am a bit at loss as to what to do...

I updated my update-alternatives, according to a hint from https://deltalima.org/blog/index.php/2023/06/28/how-to-set-firefox-flatpak-as-default-for-x-www-browser/comments/
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/x-www-browser x-www-browser /var/lib/flatpak/exports/bin/org.mozilla.firefox 42
sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser
...

3            /var/lib/flatpak/exports/bin/org.mozilla.firefox   42        manual mode

Restarted Thunderbird and ... still nothing.

A quick solution would be to force Thunderbird to Use xdg-open
in Thunderbird go to Settings then General then scroll to the bottom then Config Editor, search for those preference or create them if they are not present.
network.protocol-handler.app.http

network.protocol-handler.app.https

then set their value to /usr/bin/xdg-open
restart Thunderbird and it should work

Thank you! Unfortunately, that doesn't work. I tried xdg-open from the console (it is at /usr/bin) and there it works.
But I set both network.protocol-handler.app.http and .https to /usr/bin/xdg-open, restarted the flatpak thunderbird, clicked on a few links and ... nothing happens.

When I run Thunderbird from the console (with flatpak run org.mozilla.Thunderbird), each time I click on a link I get
/run/user/1000/doc/e2e4af3c/org.mozilla.firefox: line 2: /usr/bin/flatpak: No such file or directory
which flatpak gives /usr/bin/flatpak though.
The script at the given location is
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/bin/flatpak run --branch=stable --arch=x86_64 org.mozilla.firefox "$@"
and when I run it manually from terminal it opens a new tab into the already-running firefox, and if I add a URL as argument, it opens that too. So no idea what file it can not find...
